# Testing the signedness of a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I need to mask out some leading bits of an value. If the value is unsigned, I can assert (guarantee) that the some arbitrary number of leading bits are not set, that is the value is guaranteed to be limited.

If it is signed, I need to mask out the leading bits (turning the value into some nonportable heap of bits, yes, I am aware of that :-)). I would like to save the masking operation if the value is unsigned.

So I basically have

```
template<typename T, some more template parameters>
class {
    unsigned transform(T value) {
        ...
        if (isSigned(T)) {
            value &= mask;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to write an isSigned() which can be evaluated at compile time (to enable the optimizer to remove the unsigned dead code)?

Of course I could add another template parameter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You have to use partial specialisation:

```
template <bool> struct impl { static void foo(); };
template <> struct impl<true> { static void foo(); };

template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    void do_magic(T const &)
    {
        impl<std::is_signed<T>::value>();
        // ...
    }
};
```

You can use the ready-made [`is_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) trait class from `<type_traits>` rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Actually, the compiler is fully capable of optimising the dead code. But it might issue a warning …

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That's a detail. The OP may want to write code that only makes sense in one of the two cases, and the `if` statement requires you to write correct code even if it is never used. Templates don't have this restriction.

Comment: Thank you, I will go for this. The main thing what was missing was the `std::is_signed<T>` (or `numeric_limits<T>::is_signed` or even `T(-1) < T(0)` :-))

Comment: You can also create an overload that has an extra `std::true_type` and another with an extra `std::false_type` parameter, and pass `typename std::is_signed<T>::type()` as that argument. It will then call the signed or unsigned version appropriately. Signed-ness is not a good example use for that, `std::is_integral<T>` is a better use case when it is critical not to attempt to treat the argument as a number.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (T(-1) < T(0))
```

But I would put that in a template parameter and use it for specialization, not conditional code.  Conditional code based on template parameters often leads to spurious compiler warnings, such as "unreachable code" or "constant expression in condition".

Something like:

```
template <typename T, bool is_signed>
inline void apply_mask_helper(T& value) { value &= mask; }

template <typename T>
inline void apply_mask_helper<T, false>(T&) { }

template <typename T>
inline void apply_mask(T& value) { apply_mask_helper<T, T(-1) < T(0)>(value); }
```

Comment: I thought the OP already had a compile-time check for signedness and just wanted a static version of the conditional...

Comment: I will go for that and look at the generated code, usually gcc handles that quite nice :-)

Comment: @Kerrek A static conditional? AFAIK this could only work with the ternary operator, because `if` is only ever evaluated at runtime?

Comment: @drhirsch: A static conditional is what I wrote in my answer. It's a conditional that is resolved at compile time. C++ doesn't have a built-in "`static if`", so we have this template crutch.

Comment: @KerrekSB I see. I fact now I recognize that I have already used specializations as `static if` in other parts of the code, so I will go with it again.

Answer (score 2):

Use `numeric_limits` from the `limits` header:

```
if(numeric_limits<T>::is_signed) { … }
```

Like Kerrek said, I’d go with partial specialisation. Otherwise the compiler might complain that the condition’s value is known at compile time.