# Obtaining max of unsigned integer with bitwise not on zero value

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, numeric-limits

I'm trying to obtain the maximum value of a certain unsigned integer type without including any headers like `<limits>`. So I thought I'd simply flip the bits of the unsigned integer value 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << (~0U) << '\n'; // #1
    std::cout << (std::numeric_limits< unsigned >::max()) << '\n'; // #2
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not very experienced on the subtle differences between these. Which is why I'm asking if some unexpected behavior or some platform/architecture issues could occur by using the first method.

Comment: `~0U` is fine .

Comment: The standard doesn't guarantee a two's complement integer representation, so this trick is not portable, strictly speaking.  In practice, it will probably always work, but you should prefer to cast `0` to the expected type instead of specifying as `0U`, which is `unsigned int`.  For example, `unsigned long long b = ~0U;` gives you the incorrect maximum `unsigned long long` value when `int` uses fewer bits than `long long`.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Thanks for the suggestion. I'm actually using a `~static_cast< unsigned ... >(0)` to a type with the proper size.

Comment: Suggest `std::cout << ((unsigned type of your choosing) -1) << '\n';`  or `static_cast`

Comment: An answer to this question references the new standard which seems to seems to support chux's idea of casting `-1`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769068/casting-negative-integer-to-larger-unsigned-integer

Comment: @ChristopherOicles there are no negative numbers in this question, so it does not matter whether 2's complement representation of negative numbers is used or not

Comment: @M.M I misused "Two's Complement" as an easy way to specify the standard binary encoding used by all existing compilers, however the standard only requires integers to be encoded in a way such that each bit pattern corresponds to a unique value inside the range determined by the type's bit count -- so the standard only requires that inverting all bits in an unsigned integer zero must result in a value which is not zero.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles the standard requires "pure binary" representation, it's hard to interpret that to mean anything ither than 1=1, 10=2, 11=3, 100=4, etc.  I'm not convinced that it's permitted for UINT_MAX to be something other than one less than a multiple of 2 , but that discussion is too big for the comment section!

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Unsigned types have the specification "If there are N value bits, each bit shall represent a different power of 2 between 1 and pow(2,N−1), so that objects of that type shall be capable of representing values from 0 to pow(2,N−1) using a pure binary representation" See C11 6.2.6.2  A value with all bits set must be the maximum value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use -1 to set all bits to true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true), although there the problem is treated only for unsigned int type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... to obtain the maximum value of a certain unsigned integer type without including any headers

Simply assign the value `-1`

```
unsigned_type_of_choice max = -1;
```

Conversion of the `-1`, which is an `int`, to any unsigned type results in the value of *number that is one greater than the largest value* minus 1.

The following does not provide the maximum value of the destination type.  It fails when the destination type range exceed the range of `unsigned`, which is the type of `~0U`. [@Christopher Oicles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864070/obtaining-max-of-unsigned-integer-with-bitwise-not-on-zero-value#comment67016236_39864070)

```
// problem
unsigned_type_of_choice max_wannabe = ~0U;
```

Comment: The documentation for this (defined) behaviour is quoted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2711560/2436175). [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) is much clearer.

Comment: That documentation is C++.  My goal was a C/C++ solution.

Comment: Sure! To be super diligent one find corresponding sections in both standards, but it becomes really too much effort. Anyway, for C one can reference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe). I didn't go too deep, but, although leading to the same result, the mechanisms described for C and C++ differ.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't assign `~0U` to just any unsigned type, [chux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39865015/2436175) already explains why.

For C++, with the following you can get the maximum possible value for all unsigned types.

```
template <typename T>
T max_for_unsigned_type() {
    return ~(static_cast<T> (0));
}
```

You are *negating a zero of your exact type*. I use a verbose function name because it shouldn't be used for signed values. The problem is that for checking signedness the easiest way would be including an extra header, namely [type_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed). [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9729873/2436175) then would be useful.

Usage:

```
max_for_unsigned_type<uint8_t> ();
max_for_unsigned_type<uint16_t> ();
max_for_unsigned_type<uint32_t> ();
max_for_unsigned_type<uint64_t> ();
max_for_unsigned_type<unsigned> ();
```

Values returned: (see test code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f2182f03ab48413))

```
255
65535
4294967295
18446744073709551615
4294967295
```

Note: Doing it for signed types is much more difficult, see [Programmatically determining max value of a signed integer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813055/programmatically-determining-max-value-of-a-signed-integer-type).

Comment: Nice C++ solution.